# is there a way to figure out whether we are at the last slide at reveal.js?

Tags: reveal.js

I know reveal.js manages what I'm asking and uses the info internally when displaying the 4 way navigators...

But what does it take to write a function which will return true or false to say, isLastSlideOnSection?

at any point of time, SlideChanged event and getState can give us the stateObject which contains indexh and indexv values.

what does it take to figure out whether indexv+1 exists for the current indexh?

Answer (score 1):

Use `getProgress()` to determine if you are on the last slide. It will return a number between 0 and 1 to indicate the completion percentage of the presentation. If it equals 1 you are on the last slide

```js
if (Reveal.getProgress() === 1) {

  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it.

Reveal.availableRoutes().down will give you false, ONLY when you are on the lastSlide(s) on any section.

so, here is the function I was looking for:

```
function isLastSlideOnSection(){
   if ( Reveal.availableRoutes().down ) {
       return false;  // .down is availabe, so it cannot be lastSlide
   } else {
       return true; 
   }
}
```

you may also tap into .up, .left and .right to have further fun.